# Height 100% of a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with something that supposedly has to be very easy. I have two `div`, and I want them to fill the 100% of the vertical space; But I can't!

This is my code:

```css
.Contact {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.right:hover {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="Contact">
  <section class="left">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
  </section>
</div>
```

And there is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stcd2k1s/

It is a very simple question, but I can't make it work!

Thanks

Comment: Did you try refreshing your cache on the page to make sure you aren't seeing old CSS settings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276

Answer (score 1):

```
.Contact{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Try to use `vh` or `vw`.

`vh` means view of height. 
For example,

If you write `50vh`, it means 50% height of view.

If you write `100vh`, it means 100% of view.

`vw` means view of width.

For example,

If you write `50vw`, it means 50% width of view.

If you write `100vw`, it means 100% width of view.

```css
.Contact {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.right:hover {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="Contact">
  <section class="left">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob I suggest using `vw` and `vh`. What's problem?

Comment: How does using vw and vh answer the question? You are feeding him fish but not teaching him how to fish.

Comment: @Rob I'm not teacher. I'm a server. I don't have ability for teach with English. I just want to help. Why everyone be teacher?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Just update your code with:

```
.Contact {
display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100%;` to `html, body` and to your flex element, and also add `margin: 0` to the body to avoid a default margin:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.Contact {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.right {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: pink;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.right:hover {
  width: 50%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="Contact">
  <section class="left">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="right">
  </section>
</div>
```

Or in your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2no28a4/1/